# how use offset and limit with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, pagination, limit, offset

How can I use offset and limit in Go with mongodb?

I need an offset to determine order of APIs I fetch first, and I need a limit to specify number of APIs to display. Has anyone ever made one?

Description in picture[image: click here]

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`package for that.

`SetSkip` specifies the number of documents to skip before returning (it is offset).

`SetLimit` specifies a limit on the number of results.

`options` are imported from `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options`

```
db.Collection("users").Find(ctx, bson.M{}, options.Find().SetSkip(offset).SetLimit(limit))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip and limit the documents per collection as follow

```
db.users.find({}).skip(1).limit(10).sort({_id:1})
```

You can also use the [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) package for that.
It can also provide the feature like sort and populate, along with skip and limit of documents.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
                {     name:{
                           type:String
                           }
                });
userSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

Mongoose paginate takes two arguments as input ,which are filter and options

```
db.users.paginate(filter,options)
```

**filter** is the search criteria while **options** has the following fields:

> **select**: Which fields to select from the result
>
> **sort**: On which field to sort and in which order
>
> **populate** :If there is reference of Id then the populate can be done
> externally.
>
> **lean**: Should convert the result to js Object or not.
>
> **leanWithId**: Should also convert ObjectId to string in js Object.
>
> **offset**: How many documents to skip.
>
> **limit**:  The number of documents per page to be displayed.